# jQuery: return false inside of a function that calls ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tag-it

for this specific problem i am using Tag-it https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it, a jQuery plug-in that is specific to using tags

I have a list of tags i am using ajax to populate using jQuery ui autocomplete

What I need to do is issue a return false to a specific function BeforeTagAdded when the ajax call returns false, essentially saying the database rejected this tag entry, do not show the tag in the client browser

The developer states that "To clarify, just return false in your callback to reject the tag." that is what i am trying to accomplish

What I have tried in addition to the below code:

1. globalizing the result in a variable, then have ajax put the result in, just returns undefined
2. using return false and or the combination of event.preventDefault() + stopPropagation()
3. using the done or complete methods of the ajax call

The only thing the ajax call returns is a result:true or result:false
in the meantime I will work up a jsfiddle in addition to the below code

```
 beforeTagAdded: function(event, ui) {              
     if ( !ui.duringInitialization){ //do not fire on page initialization

            $.ajax({
                    url: "handlers/tags.ashx",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        idnumber: entity_id,
                        tag: ui.tagLabel,
                        operation:"tag"
                    }
                }).done(function(data){
                    if(data.result == false){
                      event.preventDefault();
                      event.stopPropagation();
                    }
                }).complete(function(data){

                });

         }
 },
```

Comment: you're preventing the default action way too late. by the time the done callback happens, the event default action has already occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is asynchronous. `complete` / `done` / `success` / etc are event handlers. They won't fire until the event representing the receipt of the HTTP response has arrived.

You can't return from inside those event handlers, or modify the event from the `beforeTagAdded` function because the `beforeTagAdded` will have finished and returned before the HTTP response is received.

You need to rethink your approach. This will probably involve **always** canceling the `beforeTagAdded` event, but programmatically *restarting* it from inside the Ajax event handler.

---

```
 beforeTagAdded: function(event, ui) {              
     if ( !ui.duringInitialization){ //do not fire on page initialization
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            $.ajax({
                    url: "handlers/tags.ashx",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        idnumber: entity_id,
                        tag: ui.tagLabel,
                        operation:"tag"
                    }
                }).done(function(data){
                    if(data.result != false){
                         something(); // that would have happened if you hadn't called preventDefault before
                    }
                }).complete(function(data){

                });

         }
```

},

Comment: ok, i follow what you are saying about why I am failing here, but i do not understand the new approach , any good refs or examples that you can point me towards?

Comment: so, here's my dilemma, i need to createTag() which calls beforeTagAdded() first, if i always prevent/stop beforeTagAdded(), wouldnt i always prevent/stop createTag() as well, as thats its first call?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just separate your AJAX from the beforeTagAdded function and use beforeTagAdded as a callback?

Something like this:

```
beforeTagAdded : function (event, ui, data) {
  if (!ui.duringInitialization) {
    // do something with the data
  }
},
initAjax : function(event, ui) {
  // make sure entity_id is defined
  var entity_id = '';

  $.ajax({
    url: "handlers/tags.ashx",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      idnumber: entity_id,
      tag: ui.tagLabel,
      operation:"tag"
    }
  }).complete(function (data) {
    beforeTagAdded(event, ui, data);
  });
}
```

Then elsewhere in your code wherever you call `beforeTagAdded()` switch it to `initAjax()`. Now you have the ajax data inside of beforeTagAdded to do whatever you need to do with it.