# jquery ui :Force selection of autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, tag-it

Ok, so here is my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920411/jquery-return-false-inside-of-a-function-that-calls-ajax) , but felt like i needed to ask a separate question as i did not fully understand what I was trying to accomplish

I am using jquery Tag-it plugin https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it, and need to tie these actions to database inserts/updates/deletes

what I am trying to prevent is when a user starts typing and does not select an jquery ui autocomplete item and focuses away by enter or tab key or mouse click,  a tag is still created for whatever that user typed...i want the user to only be able to select existing tags from the jquery ui autocomplete list, no other action can create a new tag, new tags will be created separately

see my code in action here http://jsfiddle.net/jrizzi1/2wjKR/2/

The Tag-It function has methods with pre and post events, example: CreateTag method has beforeTagAdded and AfterTagAdded events.

I was posting my db insert in the beforeTagAdded event using ajax $.post, but because the tag does not have to exist, i am getting orphaned rows for these (entityTags has tag "go" for a user, tags table has no tag named "go")

I thought that I could have the ajax post then try to prior to insert select from the table and return false to the BeforeTagAdded event, but the ajax is asynch as all the kind people below have noted, the beforeTagAdded finishes well before the ajax

I have also tried a few different things on the autocomplete widget, such as

```
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if(!ui.item){
                //http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change -
                // The item selected from the menu, if any. Otherwise the property is null
                //so clear the item for force selection
                $(".tagit-new input").val("");
            }
```

which prevents blur creating, but enter and tab keys still allow not selecting an autocomplete item

here is all of my code below, its using jquery > 1.5.2 jquery ui 1.8.12, tag-it 2.0

```
var entity_id = getParameterByName('idnumber');


function dotagit(){
        $("#myTags").tagit({
//removeConfirmation: true,         
 beforeTagAdded: function(event, ui) { //before the tag is added to the client, NOT the database    
     if ( !ui.duringInitialization){
         //console.log(ui);              

            $.ajax({
                    url: "handlers/tags.ashx",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        idnumber: entity_id,
                        tag: ui.tagLabel,
                        operation:"tag"
                    }
                }).done(function(data){

                    if(data.result == false){
                     return false;
                    }
                }).complete(function(data){

                });

         }
 },
 afterTagAdded: function(event, ui) {

    if ( !ui.duringInitialization){
        console.log('after'); 
         }
    },      

 beforeTagRemoved: function(event, ui) {

        $.ajax({
                    url: "handlers/tags.ashx",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        idnumber: entity_id,
                        tag: ui.tagLabel,
                        operation:"removetag"
                    }
                }).done(function(data){
        //console.log(data);    
            });
    },
 afterTagRemoved: function(event, ui) {
 },

onTagExists: function(event, ui) {
        // do something special
        console.log(ui.tag);
        console.log('onTagExists');     
    },          

 autocomplete: { source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "handlers/tags.ashx",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        idnumber: entity_id,
                        q: request.term,
                        operation:"query"
                    }
                }).done(function(data){
        //console.log(data);
                        response( $.map( data.data, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item.NAME + " x " + item.COUNT,  // + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                                value: item.NAME
                            }
                        }));        
                })
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                if(!ui.item){
                    //http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change -
                    // The item selected from the menu, if any. Otherwise the property is null
                    //so clear the item for force selection
                    $(".tagit-new input").val("");
                }

            }, 

            minLength: 0
                    }
                });         
    };


$(document).ready(function() {


$.ajax({  
  type: "GET",  
  url: "handlers/tags.ashx",
  data: {
          idnumber: entity_id,
          operation:"get"
                    }
  }).done(function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        $.each(data.data, function(key, value){
            $('#myTags').append('<li>'+value.TAG+'</li>');
            });

  }).fail(function(xhr, err){   
        var responseTitle= $(xhr.responseText).filter('title').get(0);
        alert($(responseTitle).text() + "\n" + formatErrorMessage(xhr, err) ); 
  }).complete(function(){
        dotagit();  
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With tag-it, I don't believe this will be possible without modifying the source. (I'm willing to be corrected here!) If you can be flexible with your implementation, I'd recommend [jQuery TokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/), which can do this by default. (Set `allowFreeTagging: false`).

Anyway, with regards to modifying the tagit source. The blur-add, and enter/tab-add are handled separately.

Enter/Tab add is lines 269-272

```
 if (!(that.options.autocomplete.autoFocus && that.tagInput.data('autocomplete-open'))) {
                                that.tagInput.autocomplete('close');
                                that.createTag(that._cleanedInput());
}
```

Blur add is line 277-9

```
if (!that.tagInput.data('autocomplete-open')) {
                        that.createTag(that._cleanedInput());
                    }
```

Now, I believe if you comment out the two `createTag` lines, then you'll have the behaviour that you can only add tags by clicking on them in the list. (Which I believe is handled on line 286.) Alternatively, if you still wish to be able to add tags on blur/enter, just only when they are in the database, you may wish to insert your AJAX calls at this point - and add the `createTag` lines to `done` block of your AJAX.

(Line numbers refer to v2.0, current [GitHub Version](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/js/tag-it.js).)

Comment: I am of the same mind, and altered the source at line 246, i will keep the question open so someone can prove us wrong